# C current directory within Child process

Tags: python, c, linux, process

I am writing a custom PAM module.

I have written a shared object (.so) file as required for Linux-PAM. What this .so file does, is call embedded Python to open up my facial recognition and , depending on the outcome, will return PAM_SUCCESS or PAM_AUTH_ERR

In the /etc/pam.d/sudo file I have told PAM that the file resides in (/home/berns/2020-ca326-cberns-fileencryption-with-opencv/PAM/pam_authnew.so). This is okay as , when sudo is typed, I can see my own personal error statement being printed saying it could not load the Python file.

The issue I have is, the facial recognition code resides in a total different directory from where the .so file resides. (../code/facial). I have used a chdir command in my C code, but it does'nt seem to change the directory back to where the Python facial files reside to provide success or not.

Is there something I'm missing ?

C code given below:

```
#define PAM_SM_AUTH
#define PAM_SM_ACCOUNT
#define PAM_SM_SESSION
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include </usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv){

}



PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ){

    char *result;
    chdir("../code/facial"); // this changes it to the correct directory to execute


    //dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so",RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    Py_Initialize(); // Starts python interpreter
    PyRun_SimpleString("import os\nimport sys\nsys.path.append(os.getcwd())"); // lets python know where we are

    PyObject *mymod, *func1, *ret1;
    mymod = PyImport_ImportModule("pam_detect"); // This is the .py
    if (mymod != NULL){ // check if the file file was loaded
        func1 =  PyObject_GetAttrString(mymod, "detect"); // hel is the function name in the file you declared earlier
        ret1 = PyObject_CallObject(func1, NULL); // Null because the function doesnt take an argument.
        result = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(ret1);
        //printf("%s\n", result);
        if (strcmp(result, "success") == 0){
            Py_Finalize();
            return PAM_SUCCESS;
        }
        else{
            Py_Finalize();
            return PAM_AUTH_ERR;

        }
    }

    else{
            printf("Error: can't find file!\n");
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Error response from the terminal below

[image]

Is this due to child processes not changing the directories outside of their own running space ?

Also worth noting if I compile the C code WITHOUT making it a .so , I can load up the Python files perfectly and recognise my face.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the `chdir()` actually succeeds? It is a relative path and you probably can't know for sure what the cwd is. You should: 1) check the return value of `chdir()` and 2) use an absolute path

Comment: I provide the absolute path using chdir() ie /home/berns ..... , as for what its doing , whenever I ```getcwd``` system call, it returns the CURRENT directory from which the code has been called

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if I understand you, this line here `chdir("../code/facial");` shows a relative path

Comment: Your PAM module shouldn't change the directory because that will change the directory for any program that uses PAM. When sudo loads your module it will change the directory for sudo. When sshd loads your module it will change the directory for sshd.

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean about the absolute path , I will try now

Comment: @user253751 It calls the respective .so file which changes the directory. I am only implementing it for sudo , I dont quite understand a workaround

Comment: @user253751 is correct, if you absolutely _have_ to change the directory, do it with a absolute path, remember the previous cwd and change it back before passing control back to the caller.

Comment: @Ctx the return code for chdir was 0 , so alls seem good ..